# Monitoring tools for JavaEE app

Tags: jakarta-ee, monitoring

Are there any monitoring/logging tools for a J2EE app running in WebSphere (and also Tomcat) ? I am new to this monitoring/logging world so please let me know if any further info is needed to make a choice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lots of them, have a look at the Gartner Magic Quadrant for APM. You can download a free copy on our website (AppDynamics). We do this kind of thing along with other leaders such as New Relic and Dynatrace.

Comment: Thanks Jonah - which one of these is free?